# How to generate a bell curve (Gaussian function)

Tags: c#, math, gaussian

I'd like to be able to generate a bell curve to use for probability in procedural generation in games.
For, example if I want to generate a forest, I could give it a radius and intensity and make a bell curve of the right shape to give me the probability of whether a tree should be placed or not. I should end up with a  lot of trees in the centre and they would become less frequent as you approach the radius distance out from the centre.

I've done something similar before using a sine wave. But I have no idea how to make a bell curve. [These equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function) are greek to me. I have forgotten how to *read* them, but it would be greek to the computer anyway.

Could someone write down the equation for bell curve in C# (or python would be my 2nd choice) and maybe explain it a bit?

Comment: I think it's clear enough that Guye is looking for an expression that yields a value (coefficient of radius for tree placement) given a variable (he says it as "intensity"...we can assume he'll feed in random values here since he says it is "to use for probability"). Combined with a random direction, that's enough to draw trees with Gaussian distributed distances from a center point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure.

```
p(x) = exp(-(x-mu)^2/(2*sigma^2))/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)
```

The bell curve is also called the gaussian probability distribution.  It is basically taking *e* to the power of a negative square of the *x* value.  The rest is to make sure that it is centered at mu and scaled to the specifics of the particular problem you are modeling, and to make sure that the integral over all values of *x* sums to 1.

To generate random samples from this distribution in Python, you can do something like the following:

```
import random

sample = random.gauss(mu, sigma)
# where mu is the center of the bell curve, and sigma is proportional to its "width"
```

If you want to have a two-dimensional bell curve, it's nice to know that you can find *X* and *Y* values separately like in the above, and the 2D plot will be a 2D bell curve, where the density is highest at the center `(mu_x, mu_y)`.

Comment: Could you please explain what mu is? Can it be derived from Gamma value?

Comment: mu is typically used for the distribution mean (the average value, which also defines the peak of the bell curve).  For a 2D distribution, mu_x is the mean of the distribution along the x dimension and mu_y is the comparable mean along the y dimension.  I'm not sure what the Gamma value is that you are referring to.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Mike. I was mistaking this for some other function.